# Loop without Do End if's?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I need a 2nd pair of eyes on this.  I think its the End if but can't seem to figure it out.  I am getting Loop without Do.

```
Do While ActiveCell <> ""
    Selection.Copy
    Set myActiveCell = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Select

    With Worksheets(1).Range("a:a")
        Dim value As String
        value = ActiveCell.value

        Dim c As Range
        Set c = .Find(value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            c.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            myActiveCell.Activate
            Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete
        End If
    End With
Loop
```

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: **Do** While ActiveCell <- Is it this one you're looking for ?

Comment: What you pasted compiles fine, error is elsewhere

Comment: can you post the entire method?

Comment: I tried your code and what it does is it jumps from a selected cell (myActiveCell) four steps to the left, then finds that value in the first column of the first sheet and copies the value from myActiveCell four cells next to the found cell. Then deletes the row with the myActiveCell making the next row to step up and activate the cell from the next row and repeats until runs out of myActiveCell values. That all seems to work. What do you want it to do that does not work?

Comment: Here is the entire macro.  It imports a text file then cleans it up and takes part of the text and adds it to an running monthly spreadsheet.  Its been done in pieces so the code will not be disorganized.  Thanks

Comment: How can I post the entire macro??? I think it too big.

Comment: Voted close caused by some completely unrelated code not represented in the question and found using the most basic debugging techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I disabled all my do's and loop's and reactivated them 1 at time to find the error.

Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: So what caused the issue? It would be helpful for others in future issues to know what actually caused the issue so this could be used for reference later on.

Comment: It was caused by some complete unrelated code not represented in the question and found using the most basic debugging techniques.

Answer (score 0):

It must be content related @James, I tested your code (see my comments on you question with some made up information and that seems to work. You indicate your full code is too big to post, so I'd suggest putting a break (F9) on the Do While line in your code and look at the content of ActiveCell.

It might well be that your test needs a different kind of testing for instance on ActiveCell.Value2 to continue if your content breaks the condition.

It should be fairly easy to debug, step through the code with F8 until you think it goes wrong. At that point check all values to see what is going on.